# "Pull someone's leg" Vs "Put someone on"

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs

I was wondering if there is any difference between the idiom "pull someone's leg" and the phrasal verb "put somebody on".

The Cambridge Dictionary says [to put someone on](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/put-sb-on) means:

**To try to persuade someone that something is true when it is not, usually as a joke.**

> **Example:** She said she was planning to give her house to a charity for the homeless but I thought she was putting me on.

Also as it says, [to pull one's leg](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/pull-someone-s-leg) means:

**To tell someone something that is not true as a way of joking with the person.**

> **Example:** Stop pulling my leg – you didn’t have lunch with Bono!

As you can see within the descriptions and examples, they both can be swapped for each provided example and seems that they are interchangeable.

Please kindly enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the descriptions are very clear.  Leg pulling is always humorous deception.

Comment: Well @Bruce Murray what about "put on"? What distinguishes these two? I guess you mean "pull sb's leg" is always humorous, while "put on" can be either malicious or humorous. Right?

Comment: Yes, although be careful about 'putting someone on the spot', which means ask someone a question that is difficult or embarrassing to answer

Answer (score 0):

[**American** English...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just%20having%20you%20on%2Cjust%20putting%20you%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjust%20having%20you%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjust%20putting%20you%20on%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjust%20having%20you%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjust%20putting%20you%20on%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[**British** English...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just%20having%20you%20on%2Cjust%20putting%20you%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjust%20having%20you%20on%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

In short, ***putting*** someone on is primarily an AmE equivalent to BrE ***having*** someone on (*tricking, deceiving* them). Usually *for amusement* - hence the "gold standard" Cockney expression *Are you **having a laugh**?* for *Are you playing games with me?*

Comment: Thank you, but what about "pull one's leg"?

Comment: _Pull someone's leg_ is used in British English, if that is what you are asking. I've never heard  _put someone on_, but here in the UK _having you on_ and _pulling your leg_ mean pretty much the same.

Comment: A-friend: Well, your question text already says you're aware that ***putting someone on*** and ***pulling someone's leg*** "can be swapped", so I'm not sure what else you want to know about that aspect. I'm just pointing out that Brits mostly use ***having*** there, not ***putting***. But as @Kate says, the "legpulling" version is perfectly familiar to Brits too - check out the (British) Blackadder sketch involving [***contrafibularities***](https://blackadderquotes.com/the-blackadder-dictionary#:~:text=Contrafibularities%3A%20'Contra'%20can%20be,Contrafibularity%20is%20the%20the%20singular.)

Comment: Brits also say 'you're winding me up' with the same meaning as 'you're pulling my leg'. A wind-up is a leg-pull.

Comment: Also 'pull someone's plonker' is sometimes heard. This is a bit vulgar.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'm quite certain *pulling your plonker* is fundamentally British, but I'm not so convinced about *winding you up*. I don't remember that being in use when I were a lad - and if anything, comparing [this ***American*** NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just+winding+you+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjust%20winding%20you%20up%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cjust%20winding%20you%20up%3B%2Cc0) to the corresponding ***British*** one suggests it's actually got slightly *more* currency Stateside. But I don't know the "origin".

Comment: I don't remember it from WIWAL, either, it seemed to come in during the 1970s.